# Verifying StudentId and StudentPassword with mySql Database using Visual Basic

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am working on a school voting system. I Have tried this several times and there is no error but my login button doesn't work if I enter details and click login. 
I use Visual Studio 2013 and would be glad if anyone can be of assistance.
Thank you

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ConnectToSQL()
End Sub

'connecting to sql method
Private Sub ConnectToSQL()
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim StudentId As String
    Dim StudentPassword As String

    Try

        If con.ConnectionString = "Data source= localhost; port=3306; database= Students; user=root; password=;" Then
            con.Open()

            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT StudentId, StudentPassword, StudentName FROM members"

            Dim lrd As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If lrd.HasRows Then
                While lrd.Read()
                    StudentId = lrd("StudentId").ToString
                    StudentPassword = lrd("StudentPassword").ToString
                    If StudentPassword = TextBox1.Text And StudentId = TextBox1.Text Then
                        MsgBox("you logged in succesfully")
                        Me.Hide()
                        Form2.Show()

                        TextBox1.Text = ""
                        TextBox2.Text = ""
                    End If

                End While

            Else
                MsgBox("Username and password do not match")
                TextBox2.Text = ""
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Add example data and the expected result of your checks please.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see your problem is your first if statement:

```
    If con.ConnectionString = "Data source= localhost; port=3306; database= Students; user=root; password=;" Then
```

This checks if the connectionstring is set to this value and will most definitely evaluate to false.

I assume that you want to set these settings and then open the connection to the database and not check if these settings are the set to a specific string

To make it work just remove this if statement and just set the connectionstring like this and then open the connection

```
    con.ConnectionString = "Data source= localhost; port=3306; database= Students; user=root; password=;" Then
```

Comment: I have removed the first if statement and now con.ConnectionString = "Data source= localhost; port=3306; database= Students; user=root; password=;"  but the login button is still not working.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code and checked if the method is called correctly and opens a connection to the database?

Comment: Yes. When I intentionally ommit certain words in the connection string, it indicates that unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts but when every thing in the connection string is inctant. No error is displayed yet the button doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm going to assume you have a typo here, as it's using the username and password as the same textbox:

```
If StudentPassword = TextBox1.Text And StudentId = TextBox1.Text Then
```

Password is probably the 2nd one, forming this:

```
If StudentPassword = TextBox2.Text And StudentId = TextBox1.Text Then
```

Since you are a student and new to this, not going to get into the parameters discussion, or SQL parameters or filtering, hashing passwords or anything like that, but a couple changes:

Your else on the not hasrows:

```
MsgBox("Username and password do not match")
TextBox2.Text = ""
```

The problem with this is that in your case, having no rows just means there's no members in the database, not really information you need, or should tell someone.

Also, you don't need to blank out the username and password if you are going to hide the form anyway.  The studentFound var below is used to identify if a match was found.  We want to display an error if no match was found.

So, that gives us this:

```
   While lrd.Read()
        StudentId = lrd("StudentId").ToString
        StudentPassword = lrd("StudentPassword").ToString
        If StudentPassword = TextBox2.Text And StudentId = TextBox1.Text Then
            MsgBox("you logged in succesfully")
            Me.Hide()
            Form2.Show()
            studentFound = True
        End If
    End While
    If Not studentFound Then
        MsgBox("Username/Password Combination Not Found")
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
    End If
```

Comment: I did the exact same thing and it worked now. I really appreciate your help.